# Deserializing a string into a dictionary that contains an object

Tags: c#, json, dictionary, serialization, deserialization

I have a dictionary declared like this:

```
IDictionary<string, Rectangle> myitems = new Dictionary<string, Rectangle>();

// Populate with items
myitems["aaa"] = new Rectangle(10, 20, 30, 40);
myitems["bbb"] = new Rectangle(13, 34, 13, 232);
```

I'm able to serialize it by doing this:

```
string MyDictionaryToJson(IDictionary<string, Rectangle> dict)
{
    var entries = dict.Select(d =>
    string.Format("\"{0}\": [{1}]", d.Key, string.Join(",", d.Value)));
    return "{" + string.Join(",", entries) + "}";
}

String serializedItems = MyDictionaryToJson(myitems);
```

My problem is that I cannot find a way to do the opposite and have the serialized string converted back
into my dictionary. I'm trying not to use any additional libraries, but I even after trying this:

```
Dictionary<string, Rectangle> mynewdic = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Rectangle>>(myitems);
```

still doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: You make the json manually but hope that newtonsoft deser's it? Have you considered getting newtonsoft to ser as well as deser? Have you looked at [custom de/ser](https://blog.maskalik.com/asp-net/json-net-implement-custom-serialization/)? Have you considered using LINQ to project your dictionary to an anonymous type of string,int[] and ser'ing that/deser'ing and projecting back to dict?

Comment: "Method opposed to" should be in first comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you are trying to convert some concrete class to a custom json array.

The way you typically do this is with a `JsonConverter`

**Given**

```
public class RectangleConverter : JsonConverter<Rectangle>
{
   public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, Rectangle value, JsonSerializer serializer)
   {
      var array = new JArray {value.X, value.Y, value.Top, value.Bottom};
      array.WriteTo(writer);
   }
   
   public override Rectangle ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Rectangle existingValue, bool hasExistingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
   {
      var s = JArray.Load(reader);
      return new Rectangle(int.Parse(s[0].ToObject<string>()),int.Parse(s[1].ToObject<string>()),int.Parse(s[2].ToObject<string>()),int.Parse(s[3].ToObject<string>()));

   }
}
```

**Example Usage**

```
var myitems = new Dictionary<string, Rectangle>();
myitems["aaa"] = new Rectangle(10, 20, 30, 40);
myitems["bbb"] = new Rectangle(13, 34, 13, 232);

Console.WriteLine("Original Dictionary");
foreach (var item in myitems)
   Console.WriteLine(item);

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myitems, Formatting.Indented, new RectangleConverter());
Console.WriteLine();
Console.WriteLine("Serialized data");
Console.WriteLine(json);

var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Rectangle>>(json, new RectangleConverter());

Console.WriteLine();
Console.WriteLine("Recreated Dictionary");
   foreach (var item in result)
      Console.WriteLine(item);
```

**Output**

```
Original Dictionary
[aaa, {X=10,Y=20,Width=30,Height=40}]
[bbb, {X=13,Y=34,Width=13,Height=232}]

Serialized data
{
  "aaa": [
    10,
    20,
    30,
    40
  ],
  "bbb": [
    13,
    34,
    13,
    232
  ]
}

Recreated Dictionary
[aaa, {X=10,Y=20,Width=30,Height=40}]
[bbb, {X=13,Y=34,Width=13,Height=232}]
```

<sub>***Note** : This answer specifically deals with how you might convert a concrete class to an array (and back), How you need the data formatted (what order) is not the concern of this answer, I'll leave these details up to you.*</sub>